# My custom vue directive in a .vue file is not executing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, directive

I created a Vue custom directive for the first time. But the directive is not initialized. I tried a new project and the codepen too. I really don't know the problem!

This is my Vue component:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div my-test>Some text...</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  directives: {
    "my-test": function(el) {
      el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      console.log("This is my first directive!");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-khorana-uuhd0?file=/src/App.vue

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo. You need to call the directive like `<div v-my-test>`. For more info check: [Custom Directives](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure compliance with naming standards (have a `-` dash in the name) and to avoid conflicts, by default, all directives registered by Vue are automatically prefixed with `v-`.

So change the markup to `<div v-my-test>...</div>`. See it [working](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-sea-6h9bh?file=/src/App.vue).